# Build z3 as static library instead of DLL

Tags: z3

How can I build Z3 as an static library? I have seen that there is

`--staticlib                   build Z3 static library.`

in the python `mk_util.py` but it seems that it doesn't do anything.
It still creates the dll (almost 11Mb) and the lib that doesn't have all the code since it's only 145Kb.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a known issue. Try deleting the .lib and .dll and run nmake again. In some cases it works the second time around.

Edit: I added a new entry in our issue tracker so we don't forget to fix this ([here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/456)).

Comment: Yes, that's what it should do, but it might take more than one attempt.